# Docker run does not produce any endpoint

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to dockerize [this repo](https://github.com/PrashantSaikia/LayoutLMv2-FUNSD). After building it like so:

```
docker build -t layoutlm-v2 .
```

I try to run it like so:

```
docker run -d -p 5001:5000 layoutlm-v2
```

It downloads the necessary libraries and packages:

[image]

And then nothing... No errors, no endpoints generated, just radio silence.

What's wrong? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be expecting your application to offer a service on port 5000, but it doesn't appear as if that's how your code behaves.

Looking at your code, you seem to be launching a service using `gradio`. According the [quickstart](https://gradio.app/quickstart/), calling `gr.Interface(...).launch()` will launch a service on `localhost:7860`, and indeed, if you inspect a container booted from your image, we see:

```
root@74cf8b2463ab:/app# ss -tln
State       Recv-Q      Send-Q           Local Address:Port           Peer Address:Port     Process
LISTEN      0           2048                 127.0.0.1:7860                0.0.0.0:*
```

There's no way to access a service listening on `localhost` from outside the container, so we need to figure out how to fix that.

Looking at [these docs](https://www.gradio.app/docs/#routes-header), it looks like you can control the listen address using the `server_name` parameter:

> `server_name`
>
> to make app accessible on local network, set this to "0.0.0.0". Can be set by environment variable GRADIO_SERVER_NAME. If None, will use "127.0.0.1".

So if we run your image like this:

```
docker run -p 7860:7860 -e GRADIO_SERVER_NAME=0.0.0.0 layoutlm-v2
```

Then we should be able to access the interface on the host at http://localhost:7860/...and indeed, that seems to work:

[image]

---

Unrelated to your question:

- You're setting up a virtual environment in your Dockerfile, but you're not using it, primarily because of a typo here:

  ```
  ENV PATH="VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
  ```

  You're missing a `$` on `$VIRTUAL_ENV`.
- You could optimize the order of operations in your Dockerfile. Right now, making a simple change to your Dockerfile (e.g, editing the `CMD` setting) will cause much of your image to be rebuilt. You could avoid that by restructuring the Dockerfile like this:

  ```
  FROM python:3.9

  # Install dependencies
  RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr

  RUN pip install virtualenv && virtualenv venv -p python3
  ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/venv
  ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

  WORKDIR /app
  COPY requirements.txt ./
  RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

  RUN git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git
  RUN python -m pip install -e detectron2

  COPY . /app

  # Run the application:
  CMD ["python", "-u", "app.py"]
  ```

Comment: Oh, I see. But its still strange that the console still never shows that this is the URL you need to go to to access the app. It still remains static at the end of the downloads, and then nothing. That's weird, right? Because in local, it always outputs that you can access the app at http://localhost:5001

Comment: Oh, and even more strangely, after it gets stuck if I do Ctrl+C to exit the terminal, only then it shows the links to access the app: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/39755678/195828407-1d7d2dd6-eadc-474c-bfd1-02da43f3c01b.png . 
You can see the `^C` in the fifth line in the screenshot of the terminal.

Comment: The behavior you're seeing there is probably just a buffering issue: output to stdout is typically buffered and only flushed when the buffer reaches capacity, or when it is explicitly flushed. If you replace the `CMD` in your Dockerfile with `CMD ["python", "-u", "app.py"]`, you will see the expected output (the `-u` flag enables unbuffered output).